# Is it possible to install a single instance of sql server on a server with 2 NICS and 2 different subnet?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a server that has 2 NICS and each is connected to 2 different subnet.  Is it possible to connect to this Sql server in each of the different subnet?  If so, what special procedure do I have to do to configure the Sql Server?  I am using sql server 2008.  Thank you!

Comment: I think this belongs on ServerFault

Comment: flagged for dba.se, please don't close for SF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default SQL Server will bind listen to all addresses, so it will be visible from all subnets. You can also explicitly configure SQL Server to listen on only one or the other of the NICs, see [`CREATE/ALTER ENDPOINT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181591.aspx). IT can even listen *multiple* times on each address (see [How to: Configure the Database Engine to Listen on Multiple TCP Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189310.aspx)) usually done for affinitizing clients to hard or soft NUMA (see [How to: Map TCP/IP Ports to NUMA Nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345346.aspx)).

Long story short: you don't have to do anything.